# What is the difference between a route handler and middleware function in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

My understanding is that a middleware function is a route handler with the exception that it may invoke the next function parameter to pass control on to the middleware function on the stack. Is this the only difference between a standard route handler and a middleware function?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Most of what you're talking about is semantics.  In ExpressJS, middleware can be a route handler or a route handler can behave as middleware.  So, there is not a hard and fast line between the two.  But, when people refer to middleware or a route handler in a programming discussion, they usually mean something slightly different for each...

**Middleware**

As generic terms, middleware is code that examines an incoming request and prepares it for further processing by other handlers or short circuits the processing (like when it discovered the user is not authenticated yet).  Some examples:

- **Session Management.** Parse cookies, look for session cookie, lookup session state for that cookie and add session info to the request so that other handlers down the line have ready access to the session object without any additional work on their part.  In express, this would be `express.session()`.
- **Authentication.**  Check if the user is trying to access a portion of the site that requires authentication.  If so, check if their authentication credentials are good.  If not, send an error response and prevent further processing.  If so, allow further processing.
- **Parsing of Cookies.**  Parse incoming cookies into an easy-to-use data structure a request handler can have easy access to cookie data without each having to parse them on their own.  This type of middleware is built into Express and happens automatically.
- **Parsing and Reading of POST/PUT bodies.**  If the incoming request is a POST or PUT, the body of the request may contain data that is needed for processing the request and needs to be read from the incoming stream.  Middleware can centralize this task reading the body, then parsing it according to the data type and putting the result into a known request parameter (in Express this would be `req.body`).  Express has some ready-to-use middleware for this type of body parsing with `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()`.  A middleware library like `multer` is for handling file uploads.
- **Serve static files (HTML, CSS, JS, etc...).**  For some groups of URLs, all the server needs to do is to serve a static file (no custom content added to the file).  This is common for CSS files, JS files and even some HTML files.  Express provides middleware for this which is called `express.static()`.

**Route Handler**

As a generic term, a route handler is code that is looking for a request to a specific incoming URL such as `/login` and often a specific HTTP verb such as POST and has specific code for handling that precise URL and verb.  Some examples:

- **Serve a specific web page.**  Handle a browser request for a specific web page.
- **Handle a specific form post.**  For example, when the user logs into the site, a login for is submitted to the server.  This would be handled by a request handler in Express such as `app.post("/login", ...)`.
- **Respond to a specific API request**.  Suppose you had an API for a book selling web-site.  You might provide in that API the ability to get info on a book by its ISBN number.  So, you design an api that supports a query for a particular book such as `/api/book/list/0143105426` where `0143105426` is the ISBN number for the book (a universal book identifier).  In that case, you'd create a request handler in Express for a URL that looks like that:  `app.get('/api/book/list/:isbn', ...)`.  The request handler in Express could then programmatically examine `req.parms.isbn` to get the request isbn number, look it up in the database and return the desired info on the book.

So, those are somewhat generic descriptions of middleware vs. request handlers in any web server system in any language.

---

In Express, there is no hard and fast distinction between the two.  Someone would generally call something **middleware** that examines a bunch of different requests and usually prepares the request for further processing.  Someone would generally call something a **route handler** that is targeted at a specific URL (or type of URL) and whose main purpose is to send a response back to the client for that URL.

But, the way you program Express, the distinction is pretty blurry.  Express offers features for handling routes such as:

```
app.use()
app.get()
app.post()
app.put()
app.delete()
app.all()
```

Anyone of these can be used for either middleware or a route handler.  Which would would call a given block of code has more to do with the general intent of the code than exactly which tools in Express it uses.

More typically, one would use `app.use()` for middleware and `app.get()` and `app.post()` for route handlers.  But there are use cases for doing it differently  than that as it really depends upon the particular situation and what you're trying to do.

You can even pass more than one handler to a given route definition where the first one is middleware and followed by a route handler.

```
app.get("/admin", verifyAuth, (req, res) => {
     // process the /admin URL, auth is already verified
     req.sendFile("...");
});
```

It is common for middleware to be active for a large number of different requests.  For example, you might have an authentication middleware that prevents access to 95% of the site if the user isn't already logged in (say everything except the a few generally information pages such as the homepage and the login and account creation pages).

It is also common to have middleware that is active for all HTTP verbs such as GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, etc...  In express, this would usually be `app.use()` or `app.all()`.  Request handlers are usually only for one particular verb such as `app.get()` or `app.post()`.

You might have session middleware that loads a session object (if one is available) for every single request on the site and then passes control on to other handlers that can, themselves, decide whether they need to access the session object or not.

It is common for request handlers to be targeted at a specific URL and only active for that specific URL.  For example, the `/login` URL would typically have one request handler that renders that particular page or responds to login form requests.

---

**Path Matching for `app.use()` is Different**

In Express, there's one other subtle difference.  Middleware is typically specified with:

```
app.use(path, handler);
```

And, a route is typically specified with:

```
app.get(path, handler);
app.post(path, handler);
app.put(path, handler);
// etc...
```

`app.use()` is slightly more greedy than `app.get()` and the others in how it matches the path.  `app.get()` requires a full match.  `app.use()` is OK with a partial match.  Here are some examples:

So, for a URL request `/category`:

```
 app.use("/category", ...)    matches
 app.get("/category", ...)    matches
```

For a URL request `/category/fiction`:

```
 app.use("/category", ...)    matches
 app.get("/category", ...)    does not match
```

You can see that `app.use()` accepts a partial URL match, `app.get()` and it's other cousins do not accept a partial URL match.

Now, of course, you can use `app.get()` for middleware if you want and can use `app.use()` for request handlers if you want, but typically one would use `app.use()` for middleware and `app.get()` and its cousins for request handlers.

Comment: @scottwsmyth - I added more to my answer.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks.

Comment: So Middleware is just parsing+validation. Just another buzzword.

Comment: @JuanPerez - Parsing and validation are two things middleware can be used for.  There are thousands of others.

Comment: @JuanPerez - not just. 
E.g. logging, metrics, parsing errors after handler worked..

Answer (score 8):

Ok, let's explore some definitions first.

### Middleware function

definition from the **express documentation**:

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next function is a function in the Express router which, when invoked, executes the middleware succeeding the current middleware.

### Handler function or callback function

definition from **express Documentation**:

> These **routing methods** specify a callback function (sometimes called “handler functions”) called when the application receives a request to the specified route (endpoint) and HTTP method. In other words, the application “listens” for requests that match the specified route(s) and method(s), and when it detects a match, it calls the specified callback function.

Here **Routing methods** are the methods derived from HTTP requests and the `all()` method that matches all the HTTP methods. But remind, the `use()` method is **not** a **routing method**. Let's go to express documentation for clarification.

#### Routing Methods

From **express documentation**:

> A route method is derived from one of the HTTP methods and is attached to an instance of the express class. Express supports methods that correspond to all HTTP request methods: get, post, and so on. There is a special routing method, app.all(), used to load middleware functions at a path for all HTTP request methods.

So we see that middleware functions and handler functions are not opposite of each other.

Middleware functions are functions that take an extra argument, `next` along with `req` and `res` which is used to invoke the next middleware function.
`app.use()` and the other HTTP derived methods(`app.get()`, `app.all()` etc) can use middleware functions. The difference between handler function and middleware function is same on both `app` and `router` object.

On the other hand, a handler function is a function that is specified by the **routing methods**.
So when any of the **routing methods** pass a function that has `req`, `res`, and `next` then it is both a **middleware function** and a **handler function**.

But for `app.use()` if the function has `req`, `res`, and `next`, then it is only a middleware function.

Now, what about the functions which only have `req` and `res` don't have the `next` argument?!
They are not middleware functions by definition.
If such function is used on **routing methods** then they are only `handler` functions. We use such a `handler` function which is not a middleware when it is the only one callback function. Because in such cases there is no need for `next` which calls the next middleware function.

If they are used on `app.use()` then they are not middleware, nor handler function.

Ok, enough of the definitions, But is there any difference between `middleware` functions of `app.use()` and `handler & middleware` functions of **routing methods**??

They look similar since both have the `next` argument and works almost the same. But there is a subtle difference.

The `next('route')` works only on `handler & middleware` functions. So `app.use()` can not invoke `next('route')` since they can have only `middleware` functions.

According to **express Documentation**:

> next('route') will work only in middleware functions that were loaded by using the app.METHOD() or router.METHOD() functions.
>
> METHOD is the HTTP method of the request that the middleware function handles (such as GET, PUT, or POST) in lowercase.

**If you know what is `next('route')` then the answer is finished here for you :).
In case you don't, you can come along.**

### next('route')

So let's see what is `next('route')`.

From here we will use the keyword METHOD instead of `get`, `post`, `all`, etc.

From the previous middleware function definition, we see `app.use()` or `app.METHOD()` can take several middleware functions.

From the **express documentation**:

> If the current middleware function does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.

We see each middleware functions have to either call the next middleware function or end the response.

But sometimes in some conditions, you may want to skip all the next middleware functions for the current route but also don't want to end the response right now. Because maybe there are other routes which should be matched. So to skip all the middleware functions of the current route without ending the response, you can run `next('route')`. It will skip all the callback functions of the current route and search to match the next routes.

For Example **(From express documentation**):

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  // if the user ID is 0, skip to the next route
  if (req.params.id === '0') next('route')
  // otherwise pass the control to the next middleware function in this stack
  else next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  // send a regular response
  res.send('regular')
})

// handler for the /user/:id path, which sends a special response
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('special')
})
```

See, here in a certain condition`(req.params.id === '0')` we want to skip the next callback function but also don't want to end the response because there is another route of the same path parameter which will be matched and that route will send a special response. (Yeah, it is valid to use the same path parameter for the same `METHOD` several times. In such cases, all the routes will be matched until the response ends). So in such cases, we run the `next('route')` and all the callback function of the current route is skipped. Here if the condition is not met then we call the next callback function.

This `next('route')` behavior is only possible in the `app.METHOD()` functions.

Recalling from **express documentation**:

> next('route') will work only in middleware functions that were loaded by using the app.METHOD() or router.METHOD() functions.

**That means this `next('route')` can be invoked only from `handler & middleware` functions. The only `middleware` functions of `app.use()` can not invoke it.**

Since skipping all callback functions of the current route is **not** possible in `app.use()`, we should be careful here. We should only use the middleware functions in `app.use()` which need not be skipped in any condition. Because we either have to end the response or traverse all the callback functions from beginning to end, we can not skip them at all.

You may visit [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for more information